# Momentum operator on position eigenket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

What is the result of:
$$\mathbf{\langle x'|f(\hat{P})|x\rangle}$$
I obtained this result:
$$\mathbf{\langle x'|f(\hat{P})|x\rangle=\tilde{f}(x'-x)}$$
where $\tilde{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Working in momentum space we find:
$$\langle x'|f(P)|x\rangle=\int e^{-ipx}f(p)e^{ipx}dp=\int f(p)e^{-ip(x'-x)}dp=\tilde{f}(x'-x)$$
So you are indeed correct.